# How to make Mapbox maps (with directions.js) read only? - (and prevent users from moving markers)

Tags: javascript, mapbox

My maps with walking directions in Mapbox are not read only. Users can move the markers' original locations.

I referred to layer options

```
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-directions.js/blob/mb-pages/API.md#layer-options
```

And added:

```
var Layer = L.LayerGroup.extend({
    options: {
        readonly: true
    }
});
```

The map remains interactive and users can move markers around.

Any suggestions?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q9grgbt0/

Comment: Can you post your code in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/q9grgbt0/  You can click the markers and move them around. Any clue on how to fix them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the `options` to something called `Layer`, but you never use `Layer`. You should be adding it to `directionsLayer` instead. It should look something like this:

```
var directionsLayer = L.mapbox.directions.layer(directions, {readonly: true}).addTo(map);
```

[I've updated your fiddle with this code fix](https://jsfiddle.net/q9grgbt0/1/). I also cleaned up some of the code and got rid of the unnecessary variable `Layer`.

Comment: BTW - do you know how to solve this issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37680593/how-do-i-change-the-marker-of-mapbox-with-directionsjs-it-shows-a-and-b-markers