# How do I change the marker of Mapbox with directionsjs? It shows A and B markers

Tags: javascript, mapbox, markers

How do I change the Mapbox marker (when using directionjs)?

It shows A and B markers.

I tried editing the marker but lose directions.

```
var x= L.marker([51.508245, -0.087700], {
    icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
        'marker-size': 'large',
        'marker-icon': 'monument',
        'marker-color': '#fa0'
    })
}).addTo(map);  


// Set the origin and destination for the direction and call the routing service
directions.setOrigin(L.latLng(x)); 
directions.setDestination(L.latLng(51.508112, -0.075949));   
directions.query(); 



var directionsLayer = L.mapbox.directions.layer(directions).addTo(map); 
var directionsRoutesControl = L.mapbox.directions.routesControl('routes', directions)
    .addTo(map);
  var directionsLayer = L.mapbox.directions.layer(directions, {readonly: true}).addTo(map);
```

The above is what I tried but it broke directions. I am looking for a way to change the icons of A and B.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x48qrca8/1/

Comment: Tried it - I can change the marker colours but cannot change the icon. Fiddle with updated icon URL - http://jsfiddle.net/pq2wv4j9/4/  - the icon appears grey.

Comment: Did you look at [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/help/markers/#marker-image) on their site? That might help.

Comment: Awesome. This works. Additional question (so that I don't open a new thread): How do I hide all geojson defined markers and only show Icons? The markers are appear on top of the icons sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at their examples on how to do different marker styles. For an image, [check out this example](https://www.mapbox.com/help/markers/#marker-image), specifically at this code:

```
myLayer.on('layeradd', function(e) {
  var marker = e.layer,
      feature = marker.feature;
  marker.setIcon(L.icon(feature.properties.icon));
});
myLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson);
```

This is going into the GeoJSON properties and using the `icon` value under `feature.properties` to figure out how it should be styled.

Comment: The marker still appears on top of the icon - is there a way to hide the marker A and B and only leave the icon? This is not featured in the documentation, unfortunately. Any idea?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. My suggestion would be to make a new question either here on SO or on [GIS.SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com/). You could also contact the Mapbox folks directly through [their help forum](https://www.mapbox.com/help/).